# ¿Qué tipo de estructura de datos es esta? Python

Tags: python, flask

Estudiando Python, estoy siguiendo un tutorial excelente de Corey Schafer sobre Flask, en él hace esto (lo he extraído y resumido por razones obvias):

```py
    from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
    from folder_app import app # lo hice para seguir la estructura y que el codigo sea igual al original

    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], 1800) # key, seconds
    token = s.dumps({'user_id': 1}).decode('utf-8')
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])


    user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id'] # aca es donde tengo la duda

    print(user_id)
    print(type(s.loads(token)))
```

El código funciona, el problema que tengo es que a pesar de que como pueden comprobar (s.loads(token)) es un diccionario, yo esperaba ver algo como esto `s.loads({token['user_id']})`, o así `s.loads(token['user_id'])` o algo por el estilo. Es decir, es un `dict` pero no lo parece. Y mi duda va en el sentido si esto viene de un concepto mayor de esos que llaman "pythonic" (que no he visto hasta ahora), o es algo que solo ocurre particularmente como en este caso. Dicho sea de paso en `https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/jws/` aparece esto:
`loads(self, s, salt=None, return_header=False)` O sea, los argumentos están dentro de paréntesis.
 Espero que haya quedado claro cuál es mi duda :)

Comment: Pero cuando pones token=s.dumps(...) Lo conviertes en string. No es un diccionario hasta que haces s.loads(...)

Comment: Bueno es que en realidad el problema no es que sea dict o str... el asunto, que tiene todo el día pensando es porque el dato ['user'] está afuera de la función loads() es decir, si fuera print() pej. se pasan los argumentos dentro de los paréntesis, como acá ```loads(self, s, salt=None, return_header=False)``` o como en este caso ```Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])```, es como si estuviese escrito eso mismo asi ```Serializer(app.config)['SECRET_KEY']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te mencioné en el comentario,

- `s.dumps(..)` convierte un dict en un string firmado con una  `secret_key`.
- `s.loads(..)`  convierte un string en un dict siempre y cuando éste haya sido firmado con  `secret_key`.

(esto es el meollo de los  Json Web Tokens)

Cuando haces `s.loads(token)['user_id']` es lo mismo que hacer:

```
token = 'asdfghjk.qwertyuiop.zxcv'

# datos_decodificados es un dict
datos_decodificados = s.loads(token) 

print(datos_decodificados['user_id'])
```

Tú lo estás viendo como si `s.loads` fuera un getter para una propiedad del diccionario que resulta de la deserialización.

[Puedes probar este repl que te hice](https://repl.it/@ffflabs/jsonwebtokenserializer)

Comment: Gracias, excelente. Pero creo que compliqué un poco la cosa por no saber al principio que ```s.loads(token)['user_id']``` es un ``dict```, pues resulta que había algo que no había visto hasta ahora con los ```dict``` y es lo siguiente (de haber sabido antes hubiera hecho la pregunta más simple) ej: Ex. ```student = {'name': 'John', 'age': 23} print(student['age']) **print((student)['age'])**``` En ambos casos Python devuelve el valor de la clave del dict, en el ejemplo original no es exactamente el mismo caso obvio por tratarse de otro método, pero creo que lo explica.

Comment: De todas formas, a lo que me refería también es que en los documentos en intnt, hasta ahora no encontré un ejemplo parecido...por eso al final opté por preguntar, de hecho acá mismo en la version en inglés también la hice, y las repuestas fueron similares. De todas formas leeré con detenimiento tu ejemplo Gcs.

Comment: En general envolver cualquier cosa entre paréntesis es inofensivo, y ante la duda en el orden de resolución (por ejemplo cuando hay and+or o en operadores de coalescencia) el consejo es "parenthesise defensively".  Total, print(((({'age':23}))['age'])) igual lleva a lo mismo

Comment: Ah, fíjate que en el link q te dejé estoy usando pprint, que es más explícito al dumpear estructuras como dicts, lists, tuplas, funciones e instancias

Comment: >>>Gracias ....!